# Redirect in Ember Router

Tags: ember.js

I have a situation where we used to have a login page but now we use a separate oAuth page. I'm trying to clean out a bunch of code, but I need to worry about people who have bookmarked the login route. Ideally, I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
Router.map(function () {

    this.route('login', {redirectTo: 'index'});
})
```

and then be able to get rid of the logic in my loginRoute:

```
var LoginRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    beforeModel: function (transition) {

        var result = this._super(transition);

        if (transition.isActive === false) {
            // Route canceled for auth
            return result;
        } else {
            return this.transitionTo('index');
        }
    }
});
```

Is that possible or do I absolutely have to keep my login route?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ember-redirect`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-redirect) addon which lets you do what you want:

```
let Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType,

  redirects: {
    login: 'index'
  }
});
```